# Gap in Successive minima on lattice spanned by rational and integer combination of integer vectors

Tags: lattices, integer-programming, euclidean-lattices

We are given a rank $r$ matrix $B\in\Bbb Z^{k\times n}$ where $0\leq r\leq k\leq n$ holds.

We have 
$$\mathcal L_\Bbb Z=\{uB\in\Bbb Z^n:u\in\Bbb Z^k\}\subseteq\mathcal L_\Bbb Q=\{uB\in\Bbb Z^n:u\in\Bbb Q^k\}\subseteq\Bbb Z^n$$
$$\lambda_{i}(\mathcal L_\Bbb Q)\leq\lambda_{i}(\mathcal L_\Bbb Z)$$ 
where $\lambda_{i}(\mathcal L_\Bbb Z)$ and $\lambda_{i}(\mathcal L_\Bbb Q)$ are $i$th successive minima in $\infty$-norm of $\mathcal L_\Bbb Z$ and $\mathcal L_\Bbb Q$ respectively.

> Can $\lambda_{i}(\mathcal L_\Bbb Z)-\lambda_{i}(\mathcal L_\Bbb Q)$ depend exponentially in $i$ and $\log \max_{m,m'}|B_{mm'}|$ only (not exponentially depend on $r,k,n$ particularly)?

I am mostly interested in the gap at $i=O(1)$ regime.

Comment: L_Q is dense, so it does not have any shortest vector.

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz it cannot be smaller than $1$ in any $p\in[1,\infty]$ norm since it is an integer vector.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. I misinterpreted the definition of L_Q. It might be more clear if you move the condition that uB must be an integer vector to after the colon?

Comment: What, precisely, do you mean by "not strongly depend on $r, k, n$"?

Comment: @user44191 By this I mean it can be exponential in $i$ and $\log |B|$ but not exponential in $r,k,n$.